# What's wrong with using $-extraction?

Tags: r

`fortune(312)` and `fortune(343)` allude to the problems with using `$` to extract elements of a list instead of `[[`, but aren't specific about what exactly the dangers are.

```
The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like any other magic
if used incorrectly is likely to do the programmatic equivalent of turning yourself into 
a toad.
   -- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to access a column whose name is stored 
      in y via x$y rather than x[[y]])
      R-help (February 2012)

Sooner or later most R beginners are bitten by this all too convenient shortcut. As an R 
newbie, think of R as your bank account: overuse of $-extraction can lead to undesirable 
consequences. It's best to acquire the '[[' and '[' habit early.
   -- Peter Ehlers (about the use of $-extraction)
      R-help (March 2013)
```

Looking through the documentation for `` `$` ``, I've found that

> $ is only valid for recursive objects

and

> The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does [...] Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

So, is the argument to use `[[` over `$` because the former offers greater control and transparency in writing code?  What are the actual risks of using `$`, and if `[[` is preferred are there any circumstances where it *is* appropriate to use `$`-extraction?

Comment: sort of opinion-based, but basically I would say that partial matching is the primary danger.

Comment: `$` is fine when you know the name for sure. The problem is when people try to use `$` in dynamic code, e.g. `col = "mpg"; mtcars$col; mtcars[col]`. This is what `fortune(312)` means when it says *a column whose name is stored in y*. If the column is named `"y"`, then `x$y` is just fine, but if `y` is a variable holding a string representation of the column name, then `$` won't work and you need to use `[` or `[[`.

Comment: `$` is intended for interactive use. Your second quote from the documentation explains the potential problems in programmatic use. That said, I've never had a serious problem with it.

Comment: Also related: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/903061).

Comment: You can also search the R-Help Archives to see the contexts in which both of these fortunes originated: [fortune 312](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/303183.html), [fortune 343](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2013-March/350214.html). Both involve the situation I describe above.

Comment: @GregSnow uses the euro

Answer (score 2):

Consider the list:

```
foo<-list(BlackCat=1,BlackDog=2, WhiteCat=3,WhiteDog=4)
```

Suppose you want to call the indice according to the two user parametric variables: colour and animal species.
Parametrising the colour and the species somewhere in the code as

```
myColour<-"Black"
mySpecies<-"Dog"
```

you can make the call to index parametric easily as

```
foo[[paste0(myColour,mySpecies)]]
```

by using `[[` or `[`. However, this is not case for `$` extraction: foo$paste0(myColour,mySpecies) would not evaluate the function `paste0`.